# Is there a tool where you can export your own comments under your pics? Especially @mentions

Tags: instagram

Is there a tool where you can export your own comments under your pics?

Especially @mentions

Answer (score 0):

As per [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self), you would have to:

1. Call `/users/self/media/recent` and grab `ID` from the result. From the sample output in the above link:

   ```
   {
       "data":[{
           "comments": {
               "count": 0
           },
       "caption": {.....},
       "likes": {.....}, 
       .....
       "id": "##########",
       .....
   }
   ```

   You'll need to grab the id, `[data][id]`.
2. From here you'll need to call `/media/media-id/comments`, where the `media-id` is the `id` we grabbed from step 1. The sample output given by instagram is as below:

   ```
   {
       "data": [
       {
           "created_time": "1280780324",
           "text": "Really amazing photo!",
           "from": {
               "username": "snoopdogg",
               "profile_picture": "http://images.instagram.com/profiles/profile_16_75sq_1305612434.jpg",
               "id": "1574083",
               "full_name": "Snoop Dogg"
           },
           "id": "420"
       },
       ...
       ]
   }
   ```
3. From here, you would have to parse through `[data][from]` to limit it to comments by yourself or through `[data][text]` to search for mentions.

---

1. `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`
2. `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`